# Identifying special non alphanumeric characters in a string

Tags: javascript, regex

Im working on a password validation that should only allow a-z 0-9 and these characters `"!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~`

I tried using a regex but I'm not too good with them and I wasnt sure if this is even possible or if Im not escaping the correct characters.

```
var allowedCharacters = /^[A-Za-Z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,-.\/:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~]+$/;
if (!s.value.match(allowedCharacters)){
  displayIllegalTextError();
  return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to place the dash at the start or end of the regex, or it will try to create a character range (`,-.`). Then, `a-Z` isn't a valid range, you probably meant `a-z`. Also, you need to escape the closing brackets:

```
/^[A-Za-z0-9!"#$%&'()*+,.\/:;<=>?@[\\\]^_`{|}~-]+$/
```

Comment: `[a-z-A-Z]` is also a valid class that includes the dash. Does this work in JS?

Comment: @sln: Yes, it works because here the `-` is placed in an unambiguous position, but I would avoid this since it's rather misleading.

Comment: Well, to each his own. I would avoid leaving an unescaped `[` in a character class for the same reasonl

Answer (score 2):

Looking over the ascii chart **[here](http://www.asciitable.com/)** I see your regex could be reduced to this character range:

`/^[\x21-\x7e]+$/`

If you just want to learn special behavior of character classes, you should read up
on it via regex basic tutorials.
Note that class behavior differs amongst the different flavors.

Answer (score 0):

Simpler and more to the point using unicode: `^[\u0021-\u007E]+$`.

```
/^[\u0021-\u007E]+$/.test('MyPassword!') // returns true
/^[\u0021-\u007E]+$/.test('MyPassword™') // returns false
```

---

Now if you would like to go a few steps further and actually create a more complex validation such as: minimum length 8 characters and at least one lowercase, one uppercase, one digit and one special character:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])[\u0021-\u007E]{8,}$
```