# Validate string has no illegal characters

Tags: java, regex

Im trying to validate a string that only allows letters, numbers and these characters :

```
!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~
```

I tried doing this but its not working and allowing me to enter characters not in the regex. Im still pretty new to java and something similar was working in javascript but I cant figure out whats going on here. I think its running as if it cant find any of the characters mentioned then it will return four.

```
Pattern allowedCharacters = Pattern.compile("[A-Za-z0-9!\"#$%&'()*+,.\\/:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~-]+$]");
if (!allowedCharacters.matcher(pw).find()){
    return 4;
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

EDIT:

I also tried:

```
if (pw.matches("^[A-Za-z0-9!\"#$%&'()*+,.\\/:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~-]+$]")){
        return 4;
}
```

and

```
if (!pw.matches("[A-Za-z0-9!\"#$%&'()*+,.\\/:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~-]+$]")){
        return 4;
}
```

Comment: What do you think this code is doing or should be doing?

Comment: read the second paragraph. I said what I thought its doing...

Comment: Exact duplicate, same question you asked yesterday [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21914179/identifying-special-non-alphanumeric-characters-in-a-string/21915172#21915172).

Comment: The answer is still the same `^[\x21-\x7e]+$` which is what the engine compiles your expression into. Using a different regex flavor produced a different construct. You might get more help if you exhibit a desire to learn regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`matcher.find()` checks if string contains substring that matches regex, so with
`!matcher.find()` you are checking if there is no match of regex in tested string.

Consider using using `matcher.matches()` to check if entire string is matched by regex. In this case you will have to add quantifiers like `*`, `+` or `{n,m}` to character class to decide about passwords length. Otherwise it will only single character passwords.

Here is demo of how your code can look like

```
//                                                     here you place quantifier
//                                                                ↓
if (pw.matches("[A-Za-z0-9!\"#$%&'()*+,.\\/:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~-]+$]+")){
     System.out.println("password contains only valid characters");
} else {
     System.out.println("invalid characters in password");
}
```

**Update:**

in your regex you are not escaping `[` which makes `` [\]^_`{|}~-] `` separate character class which will be added to outer character class. This character class will not include `\` or `[`. If you are really interested in accepting only alphanumeric characters and `` !"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~ `` then consider using

```
"[\\w\\Q!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~\\E]+"
```

as regex.

- `\\w` represents `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
- and `\Q` and `\E` is quote, which is mechanism to escape metacharacters, even in character class.

Comment: great that worked. I forgot the +. Am i understanding this correctly... Without the + it only checks the first character not the whole string?

Comment: Kind of. Without `+` regex can only accept single characters, not group of them so it will only match strings containing one correct character.

Comment: @Kierchon Check my update. It may be helpful if you really want to accept only alphanumeric values and `!"#$%&'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\]^_\`{|}~`

Answer (score 1):

It's because you're using `find()` and not `matches()`. That said, I'd try the opposite, doing find on `[^<legal chars>]` (note the caret) to match an *illegal* characters.  It's faster because it'll fail as soon as it hits something illegal. Also, start with the simple legal characters, then move up from there. Regular expressions can get hard to read, and adding one char at a time that has special meaning is easier than adding them all at once.

Comment: I tried this and no luck. Check out my edits to see what I did.

Answer (score 0):

Using other answers from this question, I found this to work for me. Nothing needs to be escaped between the \Q and \E. They do that for you.

```
Pattern whitelist = Pattern.compile("^[\\w\\s\\Q!\"#$%&'()*+,-.\\/:;<=>?@[]^_`{|}~\\E]+$");

if (!whitelist.matcher(pw).matches()) {
    // error
}
```